# Trying to Build and Install apinger

Tags: 14.04, compiling, make, autotools, autoconf

I am running 14.04 server (minimal install) and I am trying to build apinger (https://github.com/Jajcus/apinger).

Here is a log of what I get when I run ./autogen.sh:

The first couple of lines point to some autoconf lib that seems to not exist on my system.
If I were to fix that I assume that the rest of the errors would go away too. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
configure.ac:31: error: AC_CHECK_MEMBER: requires literal arguments
../../lib/autoconf/types.m4:888: AC_CHECK_MEMBER is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/types.m4:921: AC_CHECK_MEMBERS is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:21: JK_AP_INET is expanded from...
configure.ac:31: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autoheader: error: AC_CONFIG_HEADERS not found in configure.ac
configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
configure.ac: You should verify that configure.ac invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE,
configure.ac: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory,
configure.ac: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal)
Makefile.am: installing './INSTALL'
Makefile.am: installing './COPYING' using GNU General Public License v3 file
Makefile.am:     Consider adding the COPYING file to the version control system
Makefile.am:     for your code, to avoid questions about which license your project uses
src/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: error: am__fastdepCC does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'am__fastdepCC' is to add 'AC_PROG_CC'
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: error: AMDEP does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'AMDEP' is to add one of the compiler tests
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:     AC_PROG_CC, AC_PROG_CXX, AC_PROG_OBJC, AC_PROG_OBJCXX,
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:     AM_PROG_AS, AM_PROG_GCJ, AM_PROG_UPC
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
src/Makefile.am: error: Lex source seen but 'LEX' is undefined
src/Makefile.am:   The usual way to define 'LEX' is to add 'AM_PROG_LEX'
src/Makefile.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
configure.ac: installing './ylwrap'
configure.ac:5: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
    If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
    See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:6: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_CONFIG_HEADER
configure.ac:11: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_LEX
./configure: line 2173: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: command not found
./configure: line 2174: syntax error near unexpected token `config.h'
./configure: line 2174: `AM_CONFIG_HEADER(config.h)'
```

Comment: This bug looks related: [lp: 
likewise-open fails to build from source in maverick](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/likewise-open/+bug/651138)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Perfect!

After doing some digging on that bug, I decided to take the same action and just remove the AC_CHECK_MEMBERS lines in the [acinclude.m4](https://github.com/Jajcus/apinger/blob/master/acinclude.m4). This proved to work fine. So far I got it to pass ./augotgen.sh, ./configure, and make.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Good! Can you post a self-answer from your comment? And accept that, so it does not stay open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

So apparently there is an even easier method. aclocal didn't like the line break characters in [acinclude.m4](https://github.com/Jajcus/apinger/blob/master/acinclude.m4) on line 41 and 42:

```
41: AC_CHECK_MEMBERS([struct icmp.icmp_type, struct icmp.icmp_code,\
42: struct icmp.icmp_cksum, struct icmp.icmp_seq,\
43: struct icmp.icmp_id],[],
```

The only other thing you have to fix (unrelated to the error above) is in [doc/Makefile.am](https://github.com/Jajcus/apinger/blob/master/doc/Makefile.am). Just change this line:

```
STYLESHEET_DIR=/usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets
```

to this:

```
STYLESHEET_DIR=/usr/share/sgml/docbook/stylesheet/xsl/docbook-xsl
```